# How to simulate a normal map where one is not provided for a photographic-style & texture-based low poly flower/plant?

Tags: texturing, uv, normal-map

I purchased [this](https://www.cgtrader.com/3d-model-collections/flower-low-poly-collection) low poly flower collection, which I am quite happy with. However, I had to recreate the material as it did not come through in the OBJ/FBX, just using the texture image provided and alpha clipping. There are no normal maps provided.

This is the basic appearance from on top so you can see the general structure that was used in many of the designs:

[image]
[image]

This is quite fine and looks good from afar and a more typical angle, but I am just wondering if there is any common method used to creating a normal map effect where a normal is not provided that might make these flowers look more natural and 3D still.

If such a common method exists, if you know, would it be possible to also use it within Unity, which is my final destination?

Thanks for any help or advice.

Comment: if you just need the normal map you can use this https://cpetry.github.io/NormalMap-Online/

Comment: you can convert your images to normal maps, as Vagabonk says, or you could try to directly plug them into a Bump node? It will use the values of your images